# WIF and ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC on a single app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, wif, adfs

I have a web site I'd like to switch to ADFS/WIF (Windows Identity Foundation).

The web site has some ASP.NET MVC and other regular (WebForms) ASP.NET.

I've seen examples for MVC and examples for WebForms, but how can I have a blend of both flavors of ASP.NET living side by side in the same web site (same domain) which still supporting WIF for SSO in each?

Answer (score 0):

WIF doesn't care whether the app. is ASP.NET or ASP MVC. Just bind your app. to ADFS using FedUtil and it will work. FedUtil just changes the web.config.

You'll lose your current authentication pages (in the sense they won't be invoked) but the rest of the app. is untouched and will work as per normal.

If your app. is not currently claims-based, you'll have to make changes to consume the claims.